# Difference in the shape of polygons

Tags: qgis, isochrone, speed

I created isochrones using Iso_area as polygons algorithm of QGIS. I created the green polygon feeding the algorithm with the speed field of the road network. Then I created the blue polygon using the same start point and the same road network, but I only added a new attribute to the road network regarding the speed and fed the algorithm with this new field. Briefly, two polygons were created using the same start point, the same road network, and the same parameters, and the only difference is that the blue one was created by applying a higher speed limit.

I supposed that their shape should be the same but larger in the polygon that was created considering higher speed limits. But, the results did not prove this. These are the created polygons:

[image]

The blue and green polygons were created as I explained above, but why, for example, in the places shown in the orange squares, the shapes are not the same. As it shows in this place, the polygon created with lower speed limits (green) can cover an area that the blue one (with the higher speed) cannot cover!

Comment: Are you sure the two polygon aren't just exactly overlapping at that point? Have you looked at the road network there to see if there's something odd happening?

Comment: Yes, I am sure they are not overlapped. I changed the picture, Now it is visible in the picture. I did not check the road network there, but I only changed the speed limits in creating the blue one. I supposed that it shouldn't change the shape. If there are paths in those places that a vehicle could pass, the speed limit should not have anything to do with the shape of the accessible area.

Comment: I've always found that isochrone polygons can be a bit weird at the edges because of the way they are created from a set of lines. Can you get the network that is within the travel time before it is smoothed into a polygon?

Comment: Make sure that when changing speed limits you haven't changed one ways (i.e. the "slow" network can use a road in both ways but the "fast" network is limited to single ways)

Comment: @Spacedman No Unfortunately the algorithm only shows the final created polygons

Comment: @JGH the road network in both polygons is the same. All parameters are the same. I only changed the speed field in the blue one. I mean I fed the algorithm with speed limits higher than what it was in the green one.